# Expired UK passport number

Tags: uk, passports

I'm a British passport holder and need to find out an expired passport's number for a passport I held with a business visa in it. I no longer have the physical copy and speaking to the Passport Office and the Home Office has proved a fruitless exercise. As I spent a period of time in India in 2001, I need to obtain an Indian Police Clearance Check and my old passport number is necessary for this. Any advice please?

Comment: I've ever only held one British passport (it's still valid), but some countries, when issuing a new passport, stamp in it something like "Issued in replacement of passport number 123456789".  I guess, UK isn't one of those countries, or this question wouldn't have been asked.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just submit the number of some random old passport you happen to have lying around, since Indian police records from 2001 are unlikely to be cross-referenced to immigration records.

Answer (score 11):

If your business visa was obtained while working for a UK company, or if you worked at a UK company after 2005, then the Human Resources department of that company would have taken a photocopy of the portrait page.  You can contact the HR department and ask them to give you a copy of their copy, or simply to tell you the passport number.  They are only obliged to keep records for 6 years (or 14 in some cases) so your luck may hold, or it may not.

Next. If you had pages of your passport certified by a solicitor or notary, they would also have taken a photocopy of the portrait page.  Law firms have a [varying retention framework](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/support-services/help-for-solicitors/practice-advice-service/q-and-as/how-long-should-i-retain-my-closed-files-in-storage/) unlike companies, and many like to preserve their archives for a long time.

If these fail, and as a last resort, you can file a [Subject Access Request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration) with the Home Office.  There is a fee for this and you must clear hurdles imposed by the [Data Protection Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/29/contents).  A Subject Access Request obliges the Home Office to give you their records about you along with what they know about you...  *if they want to*.  The SAR must be in writing, and as you have already observed, calling them is a waste of time.

If all of these do not bear fruit, then it would be reasonable to enter all '9's in the passport field and include an explanation.